# Ubuntu 23.10 hangs on shutdown on Dell XPS L502x

Tags: 23.10

I installed Ubuntu 23.10 in my old Dell XPS L502X. Everything works fine and smooth. But when I want to shutdown the laptop, it freezes on an off screen (The screen turns off but the laptop is still running).
I studied some similar posts but I could not resolve it.
How can I fix this issue?